# Create a gameObject in a gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I create a gameObject in a gameObject?
Hello everyone, i can't solve this solution problem don't really know why but it dosen't work, i am new at unity 3d, so maybe i did mistakes writting the code and thanks to all who gives their time for me.

i want a suggestion from you how can i do that without using much of cpu.

I tried:

```
GameObject.Find(..),GameObject.Instantiate,GameObject.Find("TerrainData").GetComponentInChildren
```

It didn't work.
Here's my code:

```
if (parentObj == 1)
{   
    GameObject newParentObject = new GameObject();

    newParentObject.active = true;
    newParentObject.name = "TerrainData";
    //newObjs.transform.position = loc*chunkSize;
    //newObjs.SendMessage("regenerateMesh");
    parentObj++;
}

while (m_terrainToCreate.Count > 0 && Time.realtimeSinceStartup - curTime < 0.016)
{
    Vector3 loc = m_terrainToCreate.Dequeue();
    int[] pos = getCachedChunkPos(Mathf.RoundToInt(loc.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(loc.y), Mathf.RoundToInt(loc.z));

    GameObject newObj = m_meshCache[pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]];// = m_freePool.Dequeue();

    newObj.active = true;
    newObj.name = "TerrainChunk (" + loc.x.ToString() + ", " + loc.y.ToString() + ", " + loc.z.ToString() + ")";
    newObj.transform.position = loc*chunkSize;
    newObj.SendMessage("regenerateMesh");
}
```

""linked", set the child's transform.parent " yes that would be the case.
How can i catch the "TerrainData" gameObject?

tried:

```
    GameObject newObj = m_meshCache[pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]];// = m_freePool.Dequeue();

    newObj.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("TerrainData");

newObj.gameObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform.Find ("TerrainData");
newObj.transform.parent = transform.Find("TerrainData");
```

but i think it dosen't transform the object? it transforms 'Transform'?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're asking. With Unity, you can create GameObjects freely. If you wanted to have them "linked", set the child's [transform.parent](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html) property to point to the parent object.

Comment: Yes, can you give me more examples, becouse i can't find the parent? No, i don't know how to find him. :( writed what i did above.

Comment: I suggest you post your questions in the Unity3D support forums and run through the various tutorials they have on their site. (FYI, `newObj.gameObject.transform` is the same as `newObj.transform`. And I think you only want to do your first one `GameObject.Find("TerrainData")`, the other ones you have (I think) will look for children with the matching name, but you don't have any at this point.

Comment: Well i create new GameObject "TerrainData" and i want to make all other "`newObj.name = "TerrainChunk (" + loc.x.ToString() + ", " + loc.y.ToString() + ", " + loc.z.ToString() + ")";`" children of that one GameObject.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead ...

Create a property to contain your object:

```
public Transform Terrain;
```

Then you can do something like this ...

```
terrain = Instantiate(Terrain) as Transform;
terrain.parent = gameObject.transform;
terrain.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
terrain.name = "My Terrain";
```

Comment: Sorry give me a couple sec more i am trying to understand if this will work, if i want to Instantiate a terrain i think your suggestion is correct, but in my option i am just trying to all 'newObj' make a children of GameObjectCalled("TerrainData"). I will try to remodify your code and will try to make it work. Thanks for answer.

Comment: If you keep my code as it is here it works (this is from my own codebase so i know it does) in the editor if you look at this object you will have a property called "Terrain" that you need to drop a prefab on .. once you do that you can create as many "instances" of that prefab as you want.

Comment: My world is voxel based, its a common technique used to "tile chunks" so you can build endless worlds by "stitching them together" at runtime. Does that make sense?